# Run Spark in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, instant-messaging

Previously I was using Spark Instant Messenger in Ubuntu 12.04, whenever i need to start spark, just i will run the shell script by double click(In file properties changed as "Allow executing file as Program").

But I Upgraded to 14.04, even if i change the properties as "Allow executing file as Program", Not able to run the script.
every time need to open the terminal and run the script.

Is there any other way that i can run spark by double click??

Forgive me for my poor grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file manager, go to Edit > Preferences, and on the Behavior-tab under "Executable Text Files"-section set the option to what you need: "Run executable text files when they are opened", "View executable text files when they are opened", "Ask each time"